# Driver updating

Tags: command-line, kernel, modules

I need to update the drivers being used by my **Dibcom 7000 DVB card**. I have the drivers but cannot copy them to the correct directory. I seem to not have the correct rights.

How can I change my rights or move the files?

Comment: Wheredid you get the modules?

Answer (score 0):

To move files, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mv -f -i <Source> <Destination>
```

Example: `sudo mv -f -i /home/user/test /home/user/test1`

To copy

```
sudo cp -i -v <Source> <Destination>
```

Example: `sudo cp -i -v /home/user/test /home/user/test1`